# Get record within Draw custom polygon area From MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, maps, polygon

I have a table in database with following with latitude and longitude attribute

```
 CREATE TABLE `markets` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `latitude` decimal(12,8) NOT NULL,
      `longitude` decimal(12,8) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

On Google map I have a polyline feature, where user can draw a polyline, so we can show all markets which are within that polygon.

Google may giving an array of latitude longitude
[image: polyline]

How I can query to fetch all records from database which lies within draw polygon?